# gdb input/output window

Tags: gdb

I run `M-x gdb`  using emacs integrated with the shell (-nw) but when I debug programs it doesn't display the output step by step.

I mean that it returns the output only at the end when the program finishes and there is no output displayed immediately after the output commands.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please do not cross-post your question to both StackOverflow and Emacs SE. And why are you using two different users (lu Tub and boggi65ab) to do that?